# Account merge problem

Tags: support, merge-accounts

I wrote this post instead of a comment:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/192694/132894

> It doesn't let you comment because you are using a different account now from the one with which you asked the question. Use the contact form to request account merge.

That's the account I started with:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/132893/supercreepy

Somehow it forgot all my data and created a new one when I clicked the link in the email?? Your workflow for new users is really messed up, might be worth asking on UX how to improve it.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: "Somehow it forgot all my data and created a new one when I clicked the link in the email". So what steps did you follow? Also. no need for a rant.